# Recycle Bin Script in Unix

Tags: unix

Can anybody tell me how to create a shell script in Unix to create a recycle bin i.e the code must move files to a recycle bin folder.

It must also allow the user to restore the files from it and also time stamp the filenames etc.
It should be just like the Windows recycle bin. Guys please help me...

Comment: Well let's see what you have so far...

Comment: I am thinking of overriding the rm command.. So far I achieved this `if [ $1 -eq "-i" ] then for val do if [ "$val" != -i ] then echo Do you want to remove $val to recycel bin? read choice case $choice in y) mv $val RecycleBin ;; ?) ;; esac fi done else mv $* RecycleBin fi `.. also my lead wants to override rm command exactly.. also I need to add timestamp, path, username etc.. also i need the path so that I can restore it to its exact location

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen 20+ different attempts at this, both in userspace and kernelspace: http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=unix+recycle+bin&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 ; note also that various *desktop* environments simulate this for you (e.g. Gnome or KDE), just like Windows' Explorer simulates this in Windows (deleting stuff from the command line is likewise permanent there).

Comment: when someone asks to see what you have done, you should edit your original question using the formatting controls, and not use a comment with its limited formatting ability. Good luck.

Comment: Check this easiest way to recycle the files [shell script that move all of the files you delete into the .recyclebin directory](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2015/04/write-shell-script-that-move-all-of.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
# trashit

# original script
#    http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030217172653485
#    author: Shane Celis <shane (at) gnufoo (dot) org>
#
# Sun, 20-May-2007; 06:47:22 
#    minor changes...

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "usage: trashit <files...>" >&2
        exit 2;
fi

for file in "$@"; do
        # get just file name 
        destfile="`basename \"$file\"`"
        suffix='';
        i=0;

        # If that file already exists, change the name
        while [ -e "$HOME/.Trash/${destfile}${suffix}" ]; do
                suffix=" - copy $i";
                i=`expr $i + 1`
        done

        mv -vi "$file" "$HOME/.Trash/${destfile}${suffix}"
done
```

Note: stolen from here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=623656

But there are several other solutions: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/make-rm-move-files-to-trash-instead-of.html

Personally I use a `$HOME` dir checked in to a `vcs` repo.

Comment: Hi i have some more questions.. How to restore files from the Recycle Bin? also here are some additional features that are to be added..1)A super user should be able to view, retrieve and delete files of any user. When the super user performs an action on a file that does not belong to him/her, a mail confirmation should be sent to the user, which states the files operated on and the action performed by the super user on them. Periodically dump the contents of the recycle bin.After each periodic purge, mails will be sent to all users whose files were permanently removed from the recycle bin.

Comment: @holbond : again, if you are extending the description of your requirements, the proper place to do that is in your original question and not appended  as a comment. Incidentally, your new requirements are now turning this into a major application. Maybe you should post your requirements to a 'code for hire' website and see what the bidded offers are. Good luck.

Comment: I am sorry.. actually that was my unix project.. what's this code for hire website? Do i need to pay to get the answer for the code? Help me out guys.. atleast some hints how to go on.. I am a student and I dont build applications.

Comment: First suggestion: use google. Someone somewhere most probably already solved your homework (yes, you can use google for searching the term "where to hire a coding monkey". Second: read the site faq @ http://stackoverflow.com/faq .

Answer (score 0):

I posted mine here, under "KDE4 Command Line Trash Can":

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Scripting

Handles spaces and supports Gnome and KDE trash cans which is to say, you can right click and restore the file from the GUI trash can widget. :-)